# Wordpress auth library for Codeigniter (or other framework)

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

I'm looking to build a library for Codeigniter that communicates with the Wordpress database to provide functions such as login, logout and register. Logging in through the Codeigniter app should not make a difference compared to logging in through the Wordpress site. So I can switch between the two of them without having to login twice.

I'm not looking to "integrate Wordpress with Codeigniter" and whatever else people are asking about. I just want to use the Wordpress DB to authenticate users and then create the right cookies etc.

If anybody knows of any projects already existing that would be helpful to me as I embark on this I would like to hear about them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This is an example](http://einaregilsson.com/2007/08/08/using-wordpress-authentication-in-zenphoto/) of the integration that seems to need. It is not CI, but it is only a couple of functions and can serve as a starting point.

---

**EDITED**

Revisiting the issue, it seems to me that you ask as it is cumbersome because you have to rewrite things that WP does very well.

Either way, the names of the cookies consist of a prefix and a compile id of the site, it's just a md5 of the URL of the blog. Are defined in the file "**wp-includes/default-constants.php**".

The one you're interested in could be used like this:

```
//$wp_url like this: http://domain.com, Exactly as written in the configuration
$cookie= "wordpress_logged_in_".md5($wp_url);
```

The contents of this cookie will be something like: **admin|7C1314493656|7Cdd41a2cd52acbaaf68868c850f094f9f**

```
$cookie_content= explode("|",$this->input->cookie($cookie,true));
if(count($cookie_content)>0){
    $user_name= $cookie_content[0];
}else{
    //No user identified, do something...
}
```

**Bonus Pack**

While studying the WP code was writing a small library that does just that, using the WP login and access levels directly in CI. Available in bitbucket GPL2 licensed (as WP): [CiWp-Auth](https://bitbucket.org/osferanet/ciwp-auth/wiki/Home).

Comment: Wasn't looking forward to building this library myself. Thank you greatly for sharing. A similar project in broken down parts can be found here: `http://blog.marketingadept.com/integrating-codeigniter-and-wordpress/` . I'm now excited for this project. Thanks!

Comment: This code is old. I'm glad to be useful. Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress uses MD5 to encrypt their password so you can just query the wp_users table with the username and the password after you MD5 it.  The query would look something like this:

```
$credentials = array(
    'user_login' => $this->input->post('username'),
    'user_pass' => md5($this->input->post('password'))
);
$this->db->where($credentials);
$user = $this->db->get('wp_users');
```

That should return the user account info you are looking for in the `$user` var, then you can work with it just like any other authentication method.

Comment: Sure, but the underlying authentication method would need to work like WP, create the same cookies etc. or else I could be logged into WP but at the same time not be logged into the Codeigniter app. I'd also need to research how the forgot password-function works and so, if this has not been done before. Because I don't want to simply verify the user versus the WP DB, I want the Codeigniter auth system to work seamlessly with WP.

Comment: This probably won't work. Wordpress uses the [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) library, which I think only uses MD5 as a last resort where Blowfish and Extended DES are not available. If it does use MD5 the password will be salted, and I think multiple iterations of MD5 will be run.

Comment: I have changed my own password several times by using phpMyAdmin and asking it to convert my clear text password MD5. Which works... so I think that Schmitz solution would work.

Comment: That works because Wordpress still supports plain MD5 hashes for authentication, but it uses the library I linked to for hashing the passwords of new users.